# Check the size of the data stored at the memory location

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{'change_ids': <platform.api.schema.fields.StringField object at 0x7f53465fb1d0>}
```

There are some 4,000,000 items passed in the form of list which is at the memory specified `0x7f53465fb1d0`

How do i check the size of the value when i get data in the above format

Currently I tried `sys.getsizeof(d['change_ids'])` the value returned is 36bytes

Comment: And there is no `__getitem__` method in `class StringField`